# How to control infinite looping in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automationanywhere

Using Automation Anywhere (AA), I am extracting medicine names and prices from this link:
https://www.chemistwarehouse.com.au/shop-online/238/anti-fungal-amp-warts

It returns 3 pages. While extracting the pattern based data from the website, AA code loops through all 3 pages. Upon reaching the last page i.e page 3, it does not stop and the loop goes on indefinitely.

I have watched many Youtube videos but can't seem to find the solution.

Since I am new to AA, I am unable to debug the issue.
I have tried to throw some arrows in the dark but all in vain, so need your help.

I expect that AA should stop after page 'n' and write the result in CSV.

Comment: I would presume on the last page, there is no 'next page'. Check for the existence of that to break out of the outer loop, after you process a page. (inner loop being lines of data in web page) Also handy.  https://devhints.io/xpath for Xpath to locate 'Next' button

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there's some logic you're missing.

But first, it looks like the website is to blame - if you were to go to https://www.chemistwarehouse.com.au/shop-online/238/anti-fungal-amp-warts?page=4 even though there's not 4 pages worth of options, it will take you to page 1's results. That's probably why it's infinitely looping.

[image: object clone table]

Consider something like this - object cloning the table for each page. Page 1 and 2 have 8 rows, but page 3 does not. It has 2 rows. Make a variable that's true that gets checked at the top of your loop. If it's false, break the loop. Set it to false if there's less than 8 rows.

This does not solve the problem if your last page also has 8 rows, but you get the idea.